# Javascript - Counting number of characters someone has used in their password for validation

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords, character, counting

I'm making a form which older people have to use to register for a health service. (School project)
I want to make it so that if the enter less than or more than the allow number of characters for the alert box to state how many characters they have entered in their last password to show where they went wrong. I have written or rather copied and edited the code to validate.

```
if (pw.length < o.length[8] || pw.length > o.length[25])
alert("Your password must be between 8 to 25 chacters. The one you entered had * characters")
    //Would have to remember how many were entered, and then produce it
    return false;
```

I have done a bit of researching nothing I could find.
However if you even had some pointers on how I would go about I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (pw.length < 8 || pw.length >25){
    alert("Your password must be between 8 to 25 chacters. The one you entered had "+pw.length+" characters");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: missing braces will break this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for..

```
if(pw.length < 8 || pw.length > 25)
  alert("Bad Password!");
```

`pw.length` returns a number representing the length of the password. It is not an array so you cannot try and access indexes like you're doing with `o.length[8]`. Assuming `o`is another String.

Answer (score 0):

What is `o` in this context?

why not

`if (pw.length < 8 || pw.length > 25) ...`

no need for `o.length...`

This is the problem with copy and paste, which you mentioned you did.  You got code, but don't understand it.  You would be better served writing your own code....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pw is your password input box (gotten using getElementById) you basically need to check the length of the value in the box with pw.value.length, which will return an integer. That should put you on the right track